# Upload xml data back to server using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I am currently writing an app that uses xml. I access the xml file using this -

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data/data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        data = xml;
        init(); 
    }
});
```

I then change a few elements within the data using $(data).find etc and this seems to change the values.

What I need to then do is upload this variable 'data' back to my server with the changes. I have this bit of code to send it back -

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "saveXml.php", 
    type: "POST", 
    contentType: "text/xml", 
    processData: true, 
    data: data,
    success: function(){
        console.log('should have saved')
    } 
});
```

My php script looks something like this.

```
<?php
$xml = $_POST['data'];
$file = fopen("data/data.xml","w");
fwrite($file, $xml);
fclose($file);
echo "ok";
?>
```

Maybe I'm missing something and maybe I need to encode the xml first but cannot find an example of this. However when it seems to load and I get a success callback but my xml file is now empty.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i catched what you need at all, but you should do:

**Ajax**

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data/data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        error:function(response){ 
        console.log(response);
         },
        success: function (xml) {

            init(xml); 
        }
    });

 function init(xml){
         $.ajax({ 
                url: "saveXml.php", 
                type: "POST", 
                contentType: "text/xml", 
                dataType:'xml',
                processData: true, 
                data: {'xml':xml},
                error:function(response){ 
                console.log(response);
                },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data); //check your console.log now
                } 
            });
    }
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php
    $xml = $_POST['xml'];
    //you don't need to open the file, you have the source of the file in $_POST['data']
    echo $xml;
    ?>
```

Comment: I get the data in the console.log and shows up under 'p.fn.p.init[1]
'  is this right? But it still fires an error and in the ajax request @Ispuk

Comment: check i just edited my example , really don't know what is 'p.fn.p.init[1]', it seems an array index, try var_dump() instead of echo ;)

Comment: ok instead of 'p.fn.p.init[1] ' I am now getting '#document' in the console.log and also 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation' @Ispuk

Comment: do you put this js inside document.ready? can you show enteire js?

Comment: try posting your enteire js script to jsfiddle.net then paste link to here please

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ce7CR/3/ 
Also my php file is the same as yours above

@Ispuk